# How to restore LightGray Background to initialization cells?

Tags: front-end, options, cells, stylesheet, initialization

I am running Mathematica 13.2.1 on a new MacBook Pro M2 with Ventura 13.2.1. I have done something that causes any initialization cells that I create or view to no longer have a LightGray background. I would like to revert to the previous behavior. Here is what I have tried:

1. In the Options Inspector, under Global Preferences -> Cell Options -> Display Options, I see [image]. When I click on the [image], the Options Inspector displays the following graphic: [image]. If I set Background to something like GrayLevel[0.8], it gives a LightGray background to all cells, not just initialization cells.
2. Private Cell Options lists [image]. I have tried setting it to (Background -> GrayLevel[0.8]). This seems to work, but when I look at older notebooks containing initialization cells or a packages, the gray is not there. (BTW, can anyone tell me what is "private" about Private Cell Options?)
3. I notice that in the Toolbar there is what is to me a new icon, [image], but I don't remember ever using this.
4. I have never done anything with stylesheets.

**Q:** Can anyone suggest what I might have done to cause this change and let me know how to restore the previous behavior? Can I do this without resorting to stylesheets, with which I have no experience?

Comment: Every new version is changing styles. As far as I remember, there is one of the default StyleSheets from the drop down menu Format/StyleSheet/Report/StandardReport. I prefer to create initialization cells as Code to make them look differently from Input cells. Changing the cell style seems not to change the background color.

Comment: Does `Options[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions]` in your current notebook
yield
`{StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"}`? Also what does `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "InitializationCell"}]` return?

Comment: Options[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions] -> {StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"}
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "InitializationCell"}] -> {Background -> GrayLevel[0.92]}

Comment: That's what mine says, and if I change the style `"InitializationCell"`, then the style of initialization cells changes in the notebook. Not sure where to go from here.